# Troubleshooting Tailwind CSS classNames in Next.js

Tags: css, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm working on a Next.js project and using Tailwind CSS for styling. However, I'm encountering an error related to classNames in my `page.js` file. I've checked my import statements, but the error persists. Can anyone help me identify what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

**Code snippet:**

```js
import Link from "next/link";

const getSeries = async() => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api', {cache: "no-store"});
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("Fetching failed");
      };
      return res.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Series Collection: c%FAILED","color:red",error);
    }
  } 
  

export default async function Series() {
    const {series} = await getSeries();

    return (
        <main>
            {series?.map((serie) => {
                return (
                    <div className="flex flex-col">
                    <div className="flex justify-between">
                    <div>
                        <div className="flex flex-col justify-start">
                        <h1 className="text-white font-extrabold pt-2 px-2 mt-2 mx-2">{serie.name}</h1>
                        <div className="flex justify-between pb-2 px-2 mt-2 mx-2">
                            <p className="text-orange-300 md:star_gradient font-extrabold">{serie.author}</p>
                            <p className="opacity-80 text-white font-extrabold ">{serie.rate}</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <Link href={`@/app/${serie}`} className="rounded opacity-80 bg-blue-500 text-center p-2 m-2 text-white font-extrabold shadow-sm">
                        See More
                    </Link> 
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex carousel">
                      {serie.episodes?.map((episode) => {
                        <Link className={`bg-gradient-to-b from-[url("${episode.thumbnail}")] to-black flex align-end justify-end p-2 m-2 h-[300px] w-[640px] rounded shadow-md`} href={`@/app/${serie}/${episode.id}`}>
                        <h1>{episode?.name}</h1>
                        </Link>
                      })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            )})}
        </main>
  )
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
./app/globals.css:4:0
Module not found: Can't resolve './{'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./app/globals.css
```

I suspect the issue might be related to the classNames in the `page.js` file, even though my import statements seem correct. Any guidance on debugging and resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

*Note: I need the image to be there since is a great part of my UI*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error could be due to `from-[url("${episode.thumbnail}")]`. This would make Tailwind generate a rule like:

```css
.from-\[url\(\"\$\{episode.thumbnail\}\"\)\] {
  --tw-gradient-from: url("${episode.thumbnail}") var(--tw-gradient-from-position);
  --tw-gradient-to: rgb(255 255 255 / 0) var(--tw-gradient-to-position);
  --tw-gradient-stops: var(--tw-gradient-from), var(--tw-gradient-to)
}
```

This could then lead to your build system to try to resolve `${episode.thumbnail}` as a path in some way.

Also relevant is that you cannot use string concatenation/interpolation to build Tailwind class names. As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

Furthermore, a `url()` value for `from-*` would be non-sensical, since it would resolve to a `linear-gradient()` color stop, of which, a `url()` value would be invalid. In other words, you seem to be attempting to apply the equivalent CSS from `bg-gradient-to-b from-[url("${episode.thumbnail}")] to-black`:

```css
selector {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, url("${episode.thumbnail}"), black);
}
```

Which is again, invalid CSS.

To resolve, consider using a color value for the `from-` class.

Comment: Altough this explain the reason the issue is happening I still need this to work the thumbnail is a big part of the UI

Comment: You could consider displaying the thumbnail with an `<img>` element. You hay have also intended to display the thumbnail image as a background image behind the gradient. You can achieve this by using the `style` attribute.